# How can I format a float using matplotlib's LaTeX formatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex, python-2.4

I have a number in my python script that I want to use as part of the title of a plot in matplotlib. Is there a function that converts a float to a formatted TeX string?

Basically,

```
str(myFloat)
```

returns

```
3.5e+20
```

but I want

```
$3.5 \times 10^{20}$
```

or at least for matplotlib to format the float like the second string would be formatted. I'm also stuck using python 2.4, so code that runs in old versions is especially appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
ax.set_title( "${0} \\times 10^{{{1}}}$".format('3.5','+20'))
```

in the old style:

```
ax.set_title( "$%s \\times 10^{%s}$" % ('3.5','+20'))
```

Comment: Do you have any alternatives for old versions of python? I'm stuck using 2.4, but string.format() is new in 2.6.

Comment: ok... I added it! THe double back-slashes are important to interpret `\times` correctly in matplotlib...

Answer (score 10):

With old stype formatting:

```
print r'$%s \times 10^{%s}$' % tuple('3.5e+20'.split('e+'))
```

with new format:

```
print r'${} \times 10^{{{}}}$'.format(*'3.5e+20'.split('e+'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a trivial elaboration on the previous answer in case you want to do this with an arbitrary float.  Note that you need to use the split from the `re` package to account for the possibility of a negative exponent.

```
import re
val = 3.5e20
svals = re.split('e+|e-',f'{val:4.2g}')
print(r'${} \times 10^{{{}}}$'.format(*svals))
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the [num2tex](https://github.com/AndrewChap/num2tex) package:

```
pip install num2tex
```

and format your title as:

```
ax.set_title('${}$'.format(num2tex(3.5e20)))
```

or use the `_repr_latex_()` method:

```
ax.set_title(num2tex(3.5e20)._repr_latex_())
```

which will give you the same thing.

`num2tex` inherits from `str` so the `format` function can be used as you would use it for a string:

```
ax.set_title('${:.2e}$'.format(num2tex(3.5e20)))
```

Disclaimer: I (very recently) created `num2tex`.  It works well for my workflow and I am now trying to get feedback from others who might be interested in using it.