# How to combine color and number printing formatting in matplotlib texts?

Tags: python, matplotlib

## Overview

I need to produce text on a matplotlib.pyplot plot using text that both has different colours within the same object and has a number format specifier (using `{:3.2f}.format(x)`).

## Similar posts

I have found excellent posts on how to have different colours within the same object [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041502/7530580) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185143/7530580) and they both suggest using TeX and `textcolor{}`.

This works fine but I am unsure of how to combine that with `{}.format()`.

The closest thing I've found where Tex formatting and string formatting were combined was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17307141/7530580), but I can't seem to find a way to make that work.

## Where I got to

Say I want to create a text instance showing formatted x,y values printed as a float with two decimal places (3.2f) and different colours (blue, red, respectively). Here is what I thought would work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{color}')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

x, y = 1, 2

plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
string = r"$\textcolor{blue}{{:3.2f}}$".format(x) + '\n' + \
     r"$\textcolor{red}{{:3.2f}}$".format(y)
plt.text(x=1, y=2, s=string)
```

I run into a `KeyError: 'blue'` message if I run this code.

I am sure I misunderstand how these strings are interpreted but unfortunately there isn't any good documentation on this stuff.

Is it possible to combine things like `\textcolor{}` with `{}.format()` in `plt.text()`? Or otherwise is there another way of achieving what I am after?

Comment: It's exactly as in the duplicate: `r"$\textcolor{{blue}}{{{:3.2f}}}$".format(x)`

Comment: Does that work for you? When I show the plot both numbers come out black. I also get error messages if I try to save as pgf (`Undefined control sequence`), meaning I cant try and render it in a LaTeX editor to see if it is any different there.

Comment: Yeah, it only works when exporting as `.ps`-file with the PS backend.